# BC30469: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write code that uses user input to query a data base and then display a GridView in VB 2015. I am getting a compilation error and cannot figure out what I an doing wrong.

Here is all my .VB coding. I have intentionally set variable to defined numbers for testing purposes.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class BeaversInc_GridTest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim strConnectionString As String

    Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
            Dim drDataReader As SqlDataReader
            Dim dtDataTable As New DataTable
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

            Dim intStoreNumber As Integer
            Dim dteStartDate As Date
            Dim dteEndDate As Date

            intStoreNumber = "686"
            dteStartDate = CDate("11/15/2013")
            dteEndDate = CDate("11/15/2015")

            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "CriticalFails"

            With cmd.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@StoreNumber", intStoreNumber)
                .AddWithValue("@StartDate", dteStartDate)
                .AddWithValue("@Enddate", dteEndDate)
            End With

            conn.Open()
            drDataReader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader
            dtDataTable.Load(drDataReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = dtDataTable
            GridView1.DataBind()
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The lines of code that throws the exeption is dtDataTable.Load(drDataReader)                      dtDataTable.Load(drDataReader)                                                               If i comment them out everything compiles correctly.

Comment: Surely you meant `cmd.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: yes thank you. This is my first time using VB. So learning on the go is

Comment: I have one more question concerning this. Everything is now pulling and displaying as intended. The only issue now is the date coming form the data base has time included. I want to limit the display to "mm/dd/yyy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line "drDataReader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader" was not supposed to be "drDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader"??

I think that is your problem. =D

Comment: Yes that was it thank you very much I figured it was something small I was overlooking

Comment: I have one more question concerning this. Everything is now pulling and displaying as intended. The only issue now is the date coming form the data base has time included. I want to limit the display to "mm/dd/yyy"

Comment: Try to convert, something like this: CAST(DateField AS DATE) or either CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateField, 101). There are many ways to do that, you can format it on the VB as well. FORMAT(DateField, "MM/dd/yyyy").